# JIRA: Export result in excel: Time Spent columns in days

Tags: jira

I am using JIRA tool for project management activities and used to pull the data in excel on daily basis. 
The problem is when I am extracting the data, **'Time Spent'** column data is coming in minutes and not in days. For the project tracking purpose I need data in number of days. I did some analysis to find out how I can change the option to pull the data in days but could not succeeded. 
It would be great if you can let me know the setting I need to enable/change to pull the data in desired format in excel.
Thank you.

Comment: It seems it's a bug which is not yet scheduled for fix: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-30866

Comment: @Robert: You are right it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Using Script Runner plugin you can create a new scripted field with `issue.timeSpent`(Long) divided correctly. In fact it holds seconds, not milliseconds, as documentation says. Then pull this field in Issue Navigator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking  to achieve the same with out using the plugin. Anyway this will also help.